# Will PowerPoint replace a missing custom fonts specifically to Calibri?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, embedded-fonts

I need to know for sure, if the missing custom font which was used in PPT will be changed to Calibri, not something else?

Also, aren't there yet an option to embed the custom font in PPT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harrymc's answer is correct *if* the custom font has embedding enabled. The font's author can choose to allow embedding or not. If not, then PowerPoint won't embed the font.

PowerPoint (or Windows, I'm not sure at what level this happens) uses a system called Panose to choose the *installed* font that's closest to the *missing* font. It won't always choose Calibri.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to guess, you can
[Embed fonts in Word or PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/embed-fonts-in-word-or-powerpoint-cb3982aa-ea76-4323-b008-86670f222dbc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

- In the *File* tab click *Options*
- Select the *Save* tab
- Under *Preserve fidelity when sharing this presentation*
  select *Embed fonts in the file*
- Click OK.

There are other options that you may select if needed:

[image]